# Div not updating on successful ajax request (works fine on first request)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've *header.php* file in which I've code to do *livesearch*. In that search, I've directly included 'Add to Cart' button so that user can directly add products through search only.
I've Cart div in my header file in which I display number of items in cart.

1. Livesearch result is coming absolutely fine with add to cart button properly.
2. When for the first time I add any product into cart, that replaces value of cart in header file & also replaces 'Add to Cart' button to 'Added'.
3. When for the second time I add product to cart with the SAME SEARCH RESULT, it updates value of button to 'Added' but it doesn't update the value of cart in my header. So this is the issue.

Here's my code:

**HEADER.PHP**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".searchproductbrand").keyup(function()
{
var kw = $(".searchproductbrand").val();
if(kw != '')  
 {
  $.ajax
  ({
     type: "POST",
     url: "livesearch.php",
     data: "kw="+ kw,
     success: function(option)
     {
       $("#livesearch").show();
       $("#livesearch").html(option);
       document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
     }
  });
 }
 else
 {
   $("#livesearch").html("");
   document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
 }
return false;
});

$(document).delegate('.buynow','click', function(){
    var productid = $(this).attr('id');
    var quantity = $('#quantity_'+productid).val();
    var type= $('#type_'+productid).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "db_addtocart.php",
        context: this,
        data: {quantity:quantity, 
               type:type, 
               productid:productid},
        success: function(option){
               this.value = 'Added';
       $('#carttotal').empty();
       $('#carttotal').replaceWith(option);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
<div id='carttotal'><input type='button' class='button' id='cartdetails'
value='<?php echo "Cart&nbsp(".$proInCart.")"?>' style='padding:7px;
border-radius:15px;'></div>
```

For an example if I search for 'he' it displays 14 results. For first result, if I click on 'Add to Cart' button, it changes the value of this button to 'Added' & update the Cart div. But from second request with the same search result, it doesn't update the cart however it updates the value of button to 'Added'.

Why is that? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code is not working after the first request is that you are returning false at the end of the functions.
You should change your function into something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".searchproductbrand").keyup(function(e)
{
var kw = $(".searchproductbrand").val();
if(kw != '')  
 {
  $.ajax
  ({
     type: "POST",
     url: "livesearch.php",
     data: "kw="+ kw,
     success: function(option)
     {
       $("#livesearch").show();
       $("#livesearch").html(option);
       document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
     }
  });
 }
 else
 {
   $("#livesearch").html("");
   document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
 }
 e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).delegate('.buynow','click', function(e){
    var productid = $(this).attr('id');
    var quantity = $('#quantity_'+productid).val();
    var type= $('#type_'+productid).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "db_addtocart.php",
        context: this,
        data: {quantity:quantity, 
               type:type, 
               productid:productid},
        success: function(option){
               this.value = 'Added';
       $('#carttotal').empty();
       $('#carttotal').replaceWith(option);
        }
    });
     e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe can you try doing a fiddle, maybe the problem isn't there

Comment: That seems to be working fine on fiddle, why is that it's not working on my server?

Comment: If I use $('#XXXX').append, that even works for me, too (what I tried to do on fiddle due to lack of database), now what's the problem with empty function & replaceWith?

Comment: Empty removes the selected element and child elements from the DOM, while replaceWith replaces the selected element with the new element specified.

Comment: Yeah but how is that affecting my code? I've simply removed the element & replaced it with new element.

Comment: I wan't adding div tag in ajax result, I was just adding <input> & so next time I try to update the value, it won't be able to find the specified div tag.

Comment: Ok, I see your problem now, I didn't noticed it before, when you do   $('#carttotal').empty(); what actually happens is that you remove that node from the UI, while, what you need is just to replace it, or just chenage the html content, for example with   $('#carttotal').html(options);